# How is apps script authorised before distribution?

Tags: web, google-apps-script

I wish to run a script as a webapp, running as the owner of the script.

When publishing it warns that 'You need to authorise the script before distributing the URL.' However after runnning all the functions and authorising all scopes, the message remains.

I have tried it on the sample web app script that google provides and the problem is the same.

How do I authorise the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You authorized it correctly. I looked at a webapp that has been in production for a while. It shows that same message.